# How to examine existing field values and modify other field in hook_form_alter?

Tags: forms

I have a content type with a bunch of fields attached.  When displaying the node edit form I want to hide or display one field ( using $form['some_field']['#access'] = FALSE; ) if another field has a specific value.

I am using hook_form_alter() and would expect to find existing field values within $form_state['values'] but this key isn't present even though the form fields do contain existing previously saved field values.

What am I missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In node edit form `$form_state['node']` contains full node object , from which will get the existing field values.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `$form_state['values']` is for the submitted data, I'm not completely sure if it'll be present if some invalid data is submitted.

Check the `$form` array instead for the default value of the desired field, then use the [states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states) to add some behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying with new code you can try with [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module

> Define dependencies between fields based on their states and values.
>
> Conditional Fields for Drupal 7 is an user interface to the new States
>   API, plus the ability to modify fields appearance and behavior on
>   certain conditions when viewing content.

or

if you still want try with code then you can **use ajax wrappers with change events** in this way

```
  $form['some_field']=array(
                '#type' => 'select',
                '#title' => 'location',
                '#options' => array(1,2,3),
                '#default_value' => 1,
                '#description' => t('select your news location.'),
                '#ajax' => array(
                        'event' => 'change',
                        'callback' => 'some_call_back_function',                            
                        'wrapper' => 'city-term',
                        'method' => 'replace',
                        'effect' => 'fade',
                ),
                );
```

and with callback function you can rebuild form with **form rebuild**.